# Conditionals in gulp

Tags: node.js, conditional-statements, gulp, gulp-if

I'm a bit confused over how to best set up conditionals in a gulp file and could use some clarification.

Am I right in that you cannot do ordinary if statements inside a pipe chain? If you can, how would you type it out?

Right now I'm using gulp-if to do something like this:

```
// Minify
.pipe( gulpif(env === 'production',
    minifyCSS({keepSpecialComments:0,})
))

// Rename
.pipe( gulpif(env === 'production',
    rename({suffix: '.min'})
))
```

But, these two blocks would optimally be inside the same if condition. Is this possible? I can't get that to work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [lazypipe](https://github.com/OverZealous/lazypipe) for `minify` and `rename` transforms. It would be something like this:

```
var minifyAndRenameCSS = lazypipe()
  .pipe(minifyCSS({keepSpecialComments:0})
  .pipe(rename({suffix: '.min'}));

gulp.task('build', function() {
  return gulp.src('*.css')
    .pipe(gulpif(env === 'production', minifyAndRenameCSS()))
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Base on https://www.npmjs.com/package/lazypipe

`minifyAndRenameCSS` should be:

```
var minifyAndRenameCSS = lazypipe()
  .pipe(minifyCSS, {keepSpecialComments: 0})
  .pipe(rename, {suffix: '.min'});
```

There shouldn't be any function calls inside the pipes. If the function needs some arguments separate them with commas (i.e. `.pipe(myFunc, arg1, arg2)`).

Maybe you've got the right answer by now, I'm just sharing so that other viewers will know.